# Global variable is not working between functions

Tags: wordpress

i am creating plugin for my project. i want to create one page when plugin gets activate and same way i want to delete that page when plugin gets deactivate... i am able to create page but i am facing problem while deleting page...

**my code is**

```
 global $page_id;
 register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'createPage');
 register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'dropPage');
 function createPage()
 {
   global $page_id;
   $page['post_type']    = 'page';
   $page['post_content'] = 'hello this page created by plugin';    
   $page['post_status']  = 'publish';
   $page['post_title']   = 'dpage';
   $page_id = wp_insert_post ($page);
 }

 function dropPage()
 {
     global $page_id;
      wp_delete_page($page_id);
 }
```

it's not deleting page... if i give `wp_delete_post('116')` then it's working fine... i have assigning **page id** in global variable then also i am not able to retrieve it..

can any one suggest me how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the global `$page_id` you're adding will only contain the page ID when you're activating the plugin. To store the page ID, use the [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API).

```
 register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'createPage');
 register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'dropPage');
 function createPage()
 {
   $page['post_type']    = 'page';
   $page['post_content'] = 'hello this page created by plugin';    
   $page['post_status']  = 'publish';
   $page['post_title']   = 'dpage';
   $page_id = wp_insert_post ($page);
   update_option('the_page_id_i_created', $page_id );
 }

 function dropPage()
 {
    if( get_option('the_page_id_i_created') ){
      wp_delete_page( get_option('the_page_id_i_created')  );
    }
 }
```